# how can i get all the values for the same key in different dictionary and dictionaries are stored in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict

some_dict = defaultdict(list)

index_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(506))

for d in (index_dict,idx_pred_value[0],idx_pred_value[1],idx_pred_value[2],idx_pred_value[3],idx_pred_value[4],idx_pred_value[5],idx_pred_value[6],idx_pred_value[7],idx_pred_value[8],idx_pred_value[9],idx_pred_value[10],idx_pred_value[11],idx_pred_value[12],idx_pred_value[13],idx_pred_value[14],idx_pred_value[15],idx_pred_value[16],idx_pred_value[17],idx_pred_value[18],idx_pred_value[19],idx_pred_value[20],idx_pred_value[21],idx_pred_value[22],idx_pred_value[23],idx_pred_value[24],idx_pred_value[25],idx_pred_value[26],idx_pred_value[27],idx_pred_value[28],idx_pred_value[29]):
    for key, value in d.items():
        some_dict[key].append(value)
```

here idx_pred_value is my list of dictionaries.
each dicitonary contains some value with respect to a index value
i want to combine all value with same index(key)

although from above code i am able to that but is there any generalize way to access dictionary rather mentioning each dicitionary as individual element of the list

Comment: you should format your code as code!

Comment: Provide the input and expected output ! The question is not clear

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: @Solen'ya i have a list of dictionaries and from these dictionary i want to create a final dictionary which contains unique key and all the value associated with it from list of dictionary. Although i was able to create one with code mentioned above but for getting this i have written each dictionary . So my question is if there is larger number of dictionaries(i.e 100) it become difficult to mention individual dictionary in the for loop. how can i generalize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do :

```
list_of_dicts = [index_dict]+[idx_pred_value[i] for i in range(30)]
for d in list_of_dicts:
```

instead of explicitly writing out the list of dictionaries.